# Not every value has an address, but every variable does, how to understand this sentence?

Tags: go, pointers

One sentence from the book "The Go Programming Language":

> A pointer value is the address of a variable. A pointer is thus the
> location at which a value is stored. Not every value has an address,
> but every variable does. Not every value has an address, but every
> variable does.

How to understand these sentences?

- Which kind of value has no address (is unaddressable）?

Comment: The value 3, for example.

Comment: @TimRoberts you are right, the constant value is not addressable

Comment: The `nil` for instance

Comment: A map element is not a variable, and we cannot take its address. One reason that we can’t take the address of a map element is that growing a map might cause rehashing of existing elements into new storage locations, thus potentially invalidating the address.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read here [https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/GoAddressableValues](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/programming/GoAddressableValues)

Values from a return function, method call and map are unaddressable.

Read the link for more detail.